# How to uninstall Eset NOD32 Antivirus 4 from 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, antivirus

I installed  Eset NOD32 Antivirus 4 for Linux on my desktop with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit. Now my system has slowed to a crawl and is basically unusable. Eset keeps popping up asking me to Activate it; I choose Trial (I haven't bought it yet) and I fill out the name and email, click Activate. It either goes away to return later asking the same question, or it freezes for a while.

My other programs (Thunderbird, eg.) operate sluggishly for a few moments and then freeze for long periods.

How can I uninstall this Eset monster from my system? Especially given the state it's in? I have a low level of knowledge but can follow directions. Thanks!

Comment: pls point us to the howto you used to install it, or be a bit more clear how you installed it

Answer (score 0):

Usually Eset nod32 installs an uninstaller automatically. Simply search for eset in the typical "search your computer" bar and it should point you the uninstaller. Run it and voila!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/713101)

Comment: @KarlRichter, this is an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use nautilus to view the following folder:

/opt/eset/esets/bin/esets_gil

Double click on the icon (***esets_gil***), key in your password and follow the on-screen instructions to uninstall. You 'll need to reboot to complete the uninstallation. Cheers.